# PowerShell Select-String output limited to 1,000 characters?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to extract lines from a log file that start with a specific pattern using PowerShell. As long as the line content is under 1,000 characters, using the following successfully extracts what I need:

```
Select-String -Path "debug.log" -Pattern '{"id":0,"code":"OE#' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line | Out-File -FilePath test.log
```

If the line content is over 1,000 characters, the above code only returns the first 1,000 characters.

In addition to the above I have tried adding the following to the end of the command:

```
Format-Table -Autosize -Wrap
```

and also:

```
Out-String -Width 4096
```

as well as :

```
Out-File -FilePath test.log -Width 2147483647
```

Comment: Try to replace `Out-File` with `Set-Content`. The `Out-File` cmdlet is intended for formatted output and as such might run into limitations with long lines.

Comment: The output it still limited to the first 1,000 characters. Does it have anything to do with the Select-String function and how it extracts the text from the file?

Comment: Possibly. I'm not using `Select-String` that much. An alternative that is also much faster, would be `& { switch -regex -file debug.log { '{"id":0,"code":"OE#' { $_ } } } | Set-Content test.log`

Comment: I tried that and it still is limited to the first 1,000 characters of the string.

Comment: That's strange. I tried it successfully with a file that has lines of 1300 characters. Are you sure lines of your file are actually longer than 1000 characters? What you are parsing looks like JSON, so there might be newlines anywhere and parsing it like a text file is not the most robust way. If the file isn't too large, you should propably use `ConvertFrom-Json` and `Where-Object` filtering instead.

Comment: To add to @zett42's comment: By using `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line`, you're ensuring that the matching lines are relayed as-is, as strings, whatever their length.
With _string_ input, `Out-File` does _not_ impose any line-length limit, as the following example demonstrates: `'x' * 1001 | Out-File -NoNewLine test.txt; (Get-Content -Raw test.txt).Length`

Comment: ConvertFrom-Json is a no go, the file isn't JSON. It looks like it's specified as XML but it doesn't appear using any kind of import into an XML object is valid. The file itself a fairly basic text file until it gets to the text I'm trying to select then it sort of looks like XML. Upon further review of the file, the data I'm trying to extract has a line feed after the 999th character. Powershell is correct but the file is borked. Is there any way to handle this within Powershell or does it need to be addressed by the vendor creating the log?